# android : MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Tags: android

HOw to Solve this? Any Help?

```
ERROR : java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /mnt/sdcard/EREADER/NewForestPonies/OEBPS/content.opf
```

Code:

```
     //Getting the xhtml file names
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                String 
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/EREADER/"+book_name+"/OEBPS/content.opf")); //ERROR HERE
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

          ..........
          ......
```

EDIT:
FOR SAX PARSER:?

```
  DataSaxHandler myXMLHandler = new DataSaxHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(Paths.getBookStorePath()+bookname+"/OEBPS/content.opf"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen..

```
    File fXmlFile = new File(Paths.getBookStorePath()+book_name+"/OEBPS/content.opf");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Comment: IT WORKED FOR ME.. THANKS A LOT... BUT I HAVE SAME PROBLEM FOR SAX PARSER PLS SEE EDIT

Comment: I used but it showing  The method parse(InputSource) in the type XMLReader is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Comment: It just SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
 saxParser.parse(fXmlFile,myXMLHandler);